# UIScrollView constraints based off storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, photos

I'm trying to have a pictures be part of a scroll view in a gallery. I added 4 constraints:  aspectRatio, Center Vertically, and a -12 margin spacing to the nearest neighbor (the view) on the left and right side.

For some reason when the UIView in the Storyboard is a 4-inch iPhone the iPhone 5 and 5s are aligned and the 6 and 6s are messed up. If I change the UIView size to an 4.7-inch iPhone (leaving the constraints alone), the 5 and 5s are misaligned and the 6 and 6s are fine. I think the initial size of the scroll view is initialized when the view first builds itself which is initially in the size of your storyboard. So I tried printing out the frame to debug. When the iPhone in the storyboard is 4.7 inch the frame prints out to (-1,83,377,500) which works perfectly. When the Storyboard is a 4 inch the frame prints out (-1,70,322,427)

I tired using scrollView.layoutIfNeeded, which helps and prints (-9,72.5,393,522) but doesn't get the frame the same as if the Storyboard was set to the 4.7 iPhone.

Edit: Screenshots

[image]

Comment: You need to explain more about how your view hierarchy is set up and what the constraints for the views in it are. If you are getting unexpected results for different device sizes, you may have stipulated too many or not enough constraints.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by hierarchy, but there's nothing inside the ScrollView. What confuses me is that the constraints are based off of what the Storyboard view is set as. For instance in the Storyboard if I go to Stimulated Metric and change the Size that affects how it gets affected in the simulation.

Comment: Where are you setting the constraints? In the storyboard or in code?

Comment: Added them in the Storyboard.

Comment: Add some screenshots of what's happening and of the constraints you've set up.

Comment: Ok screenshots added. The only thing I changed between the first two is the size of the UIView in the storyboard, the constraints stayed the same, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Do you have any yellow or red constraint warnings?

Comment: No all constraints are fine

Answer (score 0):

Ah I solved it. It seems like I was calling scrollView.frame too early. Using it in viewDidLoad is too early it can't be used until viewDidLayoutSubviews(). Massive headache gone!

Comment: Calling scrollView.frame too early? What do you mean?